# Como disminuir el tiempo de consulta a mi BD para dar opciones a mi multiselect

Tags: php, javascript, html

resulta que tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.css" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Include the plugin's CSS and JS: -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#sites_dependientes_2').multiselect({
   nonSelectedText: 'Selecciona opcion',
   enableFiltering: true,
   enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
   buttonWidth:'200px',
   maxHeight: '200',
     });
  });
  </script>
 <body>
 <form method="post" id="framework_form3">
              <div class="form-group" >
                <div class="col-sm-1" ">
                   <select id="sites_dependientes_2" name="sites_dependientes_2[]" multiple >
                         <?php

          $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mantenimiento") ;
                                  if ($conn)echo "conexion ok" ;
                                 else echo "conexion ko";
                                 $state = $_POST['framework'];
                                 $consulta="select * from direccion ";
                                 $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
                                 $sumax=1;      

     while($lista=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

                          ?> 
                                       <option id="<?php echo "man_".$sumax; ?>" value="<?php echo $sumax; ?>">  <?php echo $lista['id_celda']."/".$lista['nombre_site']; ?></option> 
                          <?php $sumax++; } ?>
                    </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
    </body>
   </html>
```

resulta que estoy haciendo consulta a mi base de datos, para dar valores a mis opciones, y asi pueda usarse para poder realizar el multiselect. Pero resulta que en mi tabla "direccion" tengo aprox. 5000 registro, y la busqueda las realiza en un poco mas de 10 segundo, como haria para que cargue rapido al cargar la pagina y para que no me muestren necesariamente todas las opciones(en este punto pienso que hay un codigo que se puede añadir al javascript, pero no encontre cual)

Comment: Te recomiendo utilizar algo llamado `vistas` en MySQL. La consulta que utilizas a menudo métela dentro de una vista, es algo sencillo. Recuerda que también son necesarias las llaves primarias y los índices en las tablas justo en los campos en donde relacionas tablas para que éstas tengan un menor tiempo de ejecución. Asimismo, te recomiendo medir el tiempo de respuesta desde la consola de Google Chrome antes y después de hacerte la recomendación que te dije. Si esto te ayudó, no olvides hacérmelo saber, saludos.

Comment: hola @FernandoUrban , cree las vistas como me mencionaste. El tiempo de demora es de 6 seg aprox. pero como hago dos consultas identicas, entonces bordean los 10 segundos, habra alguna otra manera de que la consulta sea minima(pero el crear vistas si disminuyo un poco el tiempo, gracias.)

Comment: Por favor también revisa que todas tus tablas tengan índices, esto ayuda mucho a disminuir el tiempo de ejecución de una consulta.

Comment: solo es una tabla con dos columnas, y estoy jalando de las dos columnas

Comment: ¿Probaste también ir trayendo la información por bloques con algún LIMIT? Quizá del lado de tu vista te pueda ayudar hacer una paginación.

Comment: Te dejo esta referencia de una librería llamada DataTables que puede ayudarte a optimizar mejor la recuperación de datos y la ejecución. (https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax)

Comment: ese ejemplo es de datatables, en la cual hace consulta de un input que se realiza como buscador(que ya viene predeterminado en el datatables). en mi caso es un select multiple, entonces en la cual se va a buscar un valor de los 5000 que presento, pero no se sabe cual